# Solving partial fraction involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, self-learning, partial-fractions

[image]

---

This is the image of a part of the problem that I am doing.
I understand partial fractions fairly well. To solve for A, you will zero out the other term(s). So, For A, if I let B = 0, I am left with teh following:
$ae^{ix}-ae^{-ix} = A - Aae^{-ix}$

**What I do not know is how A = 1. I need the steps in between.**

Comment: $ae^{ix}-ae^{-ix}=A+B-aBe^{ix}-aAe^{-ix}\implies A+B=0,B=-1,A=1$ Three Equations and two unknowns, luckily there are consistent

Comment: You "zero out the other terms" by choosing a clever value of the parameter $x$, not the unknown $B$.